# Choose a pattern which will select only WHOLE words which start with an r, s, or t regardless of case

Tags: r, match

I don't know what to put for `ptrn`

Choose a pattern which will select only WHOLE words which start with an r, s, or t regardless of case.

```
ptrn <- ""                                      # EDIT THIS LINE
reg <- gregexpr(ptrn, plath)                   # DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE
(rst_words <- Reduce("c",regmatches(x = plath, m = reg)))   # DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pattern = "\\b[rstRST]\\w+"
```

`\\b` is a word boundary, `[rstRST]` will match any word that starts with any one letter inside the brackets and `\\w+` will match the remaining letters.

See the regex working at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WO84pL/1)

Answer (score 0):

You did not share an example , however you can try `grep` after splitting the string into words.

```
x <- "Random text as an example reading where it ended"
grep("^[RST]",strsplit(x, " ")[[1]], value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#[1] "Random"  "text"    "reading"
```

Comment: @R.Schifini yes, it does. I am showing one of the way to do it. It might be helpful.